# Laravel scope query with nested belongsTo relationships

Tags: php, json, laravel, model

I have a **Product** model that needs to be connected with **ProductOptions** and **ProductOptionValues** models.

The Products::getAll() should be returned with a JSON that contains a *nested view* of the options that are connected to the product, with the product option values connected to the product option, in this way:

```
products: [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "product 1",
        ...
        ...
        options: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "option 1",
                is_visible: 1,
                description: "desc",
                values: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        name: "option value 1",
                        sku: "test 1",
                        description: "desc 1",
                        unitary_price: 5.5
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        name: "option value 2",
                        sku: "test 2",
                        description: "desc 2",
                        unitary_price: 5.5
                    }
                ]
            },
            ...
            {
                id: 20,
                name: "option 20",
                is_visible: 0,
                description: "desc 2",
                values: [
                    {
                        id: 30,
                        name: "option value 30",
                        sku: "test 30",
                        description: "desc 30",
                        unitary_price: 35.5
                    },
                    {
                        id: 40,
                        name: "option value 40",
                        sku: "test 40",
                        description: "desc 40",
                        unitary_price: 45.5
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

So, I have created 2 different tables ( Product Table create migration is omitted )

**Product Options** table

```
Schema::create('product_options', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');

    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('slug');
    $table->text('description');
    $table->boolean('is_visible')->index()->default(0);

    $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->index();

    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

**Product Option Values** table

```
Schema::create('product_option_values', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');

    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('sku');
    $table->text('description');
    $table->boolean('is_default_value')->index()->default(0);

    $table->integer('product_option_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->index();

    $table->decimal('unitary_price', 10, 2);

    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

**Product Option** Model:

```
class ProductOption extends Model {
    use SoftDeletes;
    use SluggableTrait;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
    protected $sluggable = [
        'build_from' => 'name',
        'save_to'    => 'slug',
        'include_trashed' => true
    ];

    public function product() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }

    public function productOptionValues () {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductOptionValue::class);
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

**Product Option Value** Model:

```
class ProductOptionValue extends Model {
    use SoftDeletes;
    use SluggableTrait;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

    public function product() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }

    public function productOption() {
        return $this->belongsTo(ProductOption::class);
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

**Product** Model:

```
class Product extends Model implements SluggableInterface {
    use SoftDeletes;
    use SluggableTrait;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
    protected $sluggable = [
        'build_from' => 'name',
        'save_to'    => 'slug',
        'include_trashed' => true
    ];

    ...
    ...

    public function productOptions() {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductOption::class);
    }

    public function productOptionValues() {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductOptionValue::class);
    }

}
```

Question is, how can I get a Product Object that contains, in the JSON data, also the Option Values nested into the "options" key of the product? I'm already using the ***scopeWithCompleteData*** method into the **Products** Model that is called from the JSON API handler, but can't understand how to nest & filter the values of the options and option values to represent a JSON array like the one posted at the very beginning of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try eager loading?

```
Product::with('product_option_values')->get()->toJson()
```